# Exam Question: Integral of an unknown function

Tags: calculus, integration

> A continuous function defined for $x>0$ satisfies
>   $2f(x)+\frac{1}{x^2}f(\frac{1}{x})=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}$
>   What is $$\int_{0.5}^{2} f(x)\,dx$$

The suggested answer is $\frac{2\ln2}{3}+1$, but I obtained $\frac{2\ln2}{3}+\frac{1}{2}$.

This is what I have done:[image: ng]
Did I make a careless mistake somewhere?

Was my approach wrong? Is the suggested answer wrong?

Comment: I get your answer as well.

Comment: I looked carefully at this & could not see any problem with what you had done ... So I agree with you, Greg & MilesB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your solution looks fine to me, I tried a different approach and explicitly found f(x) by assuming it takes the form $$f(x) = a/x^2 + b/x + c$$ leading to $a=\frac23, b=\frac13, c=-\frac13$

The integral of f(x) is then $$-\frac{2}{3x} + \frac13\ln(x) - \frac{x}{3}$$

Substituting in the limits led to the same answer as you, ie $$\frac{2\ln2}{3}+\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Hey I think you messed up at the first equation. It should be a/x^2 and b/x, I think

Comment: Good spot!  I did it that way on paper, I just wrote it the wrong way round in my answer.  I've edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

From

$$
\cases{
2f\left(\frac 1x\right)+x^2f(x)=x+x^2\\
2f(x)+\frac{1}{x^2}f\left(\frac 1x\right) = \frac 1x+\frac{1}{x^2}
}
$$
solving for $f(x), f\left(\frac 1x\right)$ we obtain

$$
f(x) = \frac{x^2-x-2}{3x^2}
$$